# How to reduce ttfb time in wordpress sites?

Tags: wordpress, server

How to reduce ttfb time ?
my wordpress site has very long ttfb time.
i tested result several time and result absolutely confuse me sometimes is lower than 200ms sometimes more than 5s !
what is the problem ?
network configuration or server side scripts ? or something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really a Wordpress specific problem as all websites should try to have a ttfb time as little as possible.

Generally speaking when you use a tool like [Google page Speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=fr) or [PingDom](https://tools.pingdom.com/) (to name a few), you should get some advices on how to improve your ttfb time.

Like using a cache system, compress and regroup JS/CSS files, reduce images size, using a CDN, etc...

Now on Wordpress ecosystem, you have a lot of plugins what can help you with that (especially if you're not a developper).

Here is a list of some I know and have already used that may help you:

[W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) (caching plugin) - A good free solution for setting a cache system on your WP (realivelly complicated to handle though)

[WP Rocket](https://wp-rocket.me/) (caching plugin) - an excellent non-free solution. Work pretty well (much easier to handle than W3 Total Cache). Affordable.

[Imagify](https://imagify.io/) (image compression plugin) - this plugin re-compress and optimize you medias. It is developped by the same company as WP Rocket, you need to create an account on there service to use it. And they have a free plan.

In any case, if you're not a developper, I encourage you to get help from one because some caching options can produce unwanted effects like a JS component that doesn't work anymore of stuff like that so you need to test if your website still works each time you make a change.

Note: long ttfb time can also be related to the server itself (mutualized one for example).

Hope it help.